# How to Set style property to element using Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("contentFrame");
IWebElement str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='dvCustomDateRange']"));
```

I need to change the style attribute from style="display: none;" to style="display: block;".

This is the element:

`<div id="dvCustomDateRange" tabindex="0" class="filters hidden inline-block inlineChilds NoPrint width100 marginBt7" style="display: block;">`

any idea how to do this using Selenium? Im try getAttribute and getCssValue methods to change value but without result.

Comment: But in your provided HTML, it's already shows as `style="display: block;"`. Why??

Comment: Its becouse i click manualy in page source.

Comment: So means when are you going to click during automation is become invisible??

Comment: When Im change style to none its become invisible.

Answer (score 9):

You will have to use javascript executor to set a css attribute value.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].style='display: block;'", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

executeScript() will do the trick:

```
 driver.executeScript("arguments[0].style='display: block;'",element);
```